# Selectively Import only Json data in txt file into R.

Tags: json, r

I have 3 questions I would like to ask as I am relatively new to both R and Json format. I read quite a bit of things but I don't quite understand still.

1:) Can R parse Json data when the txt file contains other irrelevant information as well?

Assuming I can't, I uploaded the text file into R and did some cleaning up. So that it will be easier to read the file.

```
require(plyr)
require(rjson)

small.f.2 <- subset(small.f.1, ! V1 %in% c("Level_Index:", "Feature_Type:", "Goals:", "Move_Count:"))
small.f.3 <- small.f.2[,-1]
```

This would give me a single column with all the json data in each line. 
I tried to write new .txt file .

```
write.table(small.f.3, file="small clean.txt",  row.names = FALSE)
json_data <- fromJSON(file="small.clean")
```

The problem was it only converted 'x' (first row) into a character and ignored everything else. I imagined it was the problem with "x" so I took that out from the .txt file and ran it again.

```
json_data <- fromJSON(file="small clean copy.txt")  
small <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("small clean copy.txt"), collapse=""))
```

Both time worked and I manage to create a list. But it only takes the data from the first row and ignore the rest. This leads to my second question.

I tried this..

```
small <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("small clean copy.txt"), collapse=","))
Error in fromJSON(paste(readLines("small clean copy.txt"), collapse  = ",")) : 
  unexpected character ','
```

2.) How can I extract the rest of the rows in the .txt file?

3.) Is it possible for R to read the Json data from one row, and extract only the nested data that I need, and subsequently go on to the next row, like a loop? For example, in each array, I am only interested in the Action vectors and the State Feature vectors, but I am not interested in the rest of the data.  If I can somehow extract only the information I need before moving on to the next array, than I can save a lot of memory space.

I validated the array online. But the .txt file is not json formatted. Only within each array. I hope this make sense. Each row is a nested array.

The data looks something like this. I have about 65 rows (nested arrays) in total.

```
{"NonlightningIndices":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],"LightningIndices":[],"SelectedAction":12,"State":{"Features":{"Data":[21.0,58.0,0.599999964237213,12.0,9.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,11.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}},"Actions":[{"Features":{"Data":[4.0,4.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.12213890532609,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.13055793241076,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.231325346416068,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.949158357257511,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.369666537828737,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0851765937900996,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.223409208023677,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.698640447815897,1.69496718435102,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.42312654023416,0.0,0.38394999584831,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.22164326251584,1.30980246401454,1.00411570750454,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.44306759429513,0.0,0.00568191150434618,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.157705869690127,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.102089274086033,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.37039305683305,2.64354332879095,0.0,0.456876463171171,0.0,0.0,0.208651305680117,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,3.46713142511126,2.26785558685153,0.284845692694476,0.29200364444299,0.0,0.562185300773834,1.79134869431988,0.423426746571872,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5.06772310533214,0.0,1.95593334724537,2.08448537685298,1.22045520912269,0.251119892385839,0.0,4.86192274732091,0.0,0.186941346075472,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.37998688020614,0.0,3.04406665275463,1.0,0.49469909818283,0.0,0.0,1.57589195190525,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.55229001446173]}},......
{"NonlightningIndices":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,24],"LightningIndices":[[15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]],"SelectedAction":15,"State":{"Features":{"Data":[20.0,53.0,0.0,11.0,10.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,12.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]}},"Actions":[{"Features":{"Data":[4.0,4.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.110686363475575,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.13427913742728,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.218834141070836,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.939443046803111,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.357568892126985,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0889329732996782,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.22521492930721,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.700441220022084,1.6762090551226,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.44526456614638,0.0,0.383689214317325,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.22583659574753,1.31795156033445,0.99710368703165,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.44325394830013,0.0,0.00418600599483917,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.157518319482216,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.110244186273209,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.369899973785845,2.55505143302811,0.0,0.463342609296841,0.0,0.0,0.226088384842823,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,3.47842109127488,2.38476342332125,0.0698115810371108,0.276804206873942,0.0,1.53514282355593,1.77391161515718,0.421465101754304,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.45530484778828,0.0,1.43798302409155,3.46965807176681,0.468528940277049,0.259853183829217,0.0,4.86988325473155,0.0,0.190659677933533,0.0,0.0,0.963116148760181,0.0,4.29930830894124,0.0,2.56201697590845,0.593423384852181,0.46165947868584,0.0,0.0,1.59497392171253,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0368838512398189,0.0,4.24538684327048]}},......
```

I would really appreciate any advice here.

Comment: Why not break this down into 2 or 3 individual questions?

Comment: I guess it makes more sense when the questions are asked together.